# SharePoint task lists VS. Enterprise project in PWA

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

We can add project in PWA in two way :**SharePoint task lists** & **Enterprise project**

Project Web App can now include SharePoint task lists in the Project Center, to support a transition from lightweight project management to a more mature enterprise project management solution. As soon as a SharePoint task list is connected to Project Web App, users can view the task list as a project in a primarily read-only state. You can include SharePoint task list projects in reports, and the assignments in SharePoint task list projects are taken into consideration when reviewing resource availability.

As work on the tasks progresses, you may determine that the project would benefit from more the robust planning and tracking features in Project Web App. You can change the connected task list into an enterprise project, and it becomes editable in Project Web App and read-only on the SharePoint site where it originated.

Is there a more detail about SharePoint task lists VS. Enterprise project ? [image: Enterprise project in PWA] [image: sharepoint task list in PWA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I can find is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679950(v=office.15).aspx#ActivateEnterpriseFeatures which says "Doing so provides additional features, such as timesheets and workflow"